# Converting struct to int and vice versa

Tags: c, generics, type-conversion, c11

In order to make some _Generic expressions work properly, it appears that the only option is to convert integer types to structure types and vice versa, with these meaningless conversions only ever being present in non selected expressions. I am having trouble definitively answering the question as to whether or not this is strictly c11 standard compliant.

Comment: Can you give an example program whose compliance is in question?

Comment: Suppose there is a structure representing a 128 bit integer, and I want a _Generic that can multiply assign that structure with either another such structure or a basic integer type, so I can define a macro to perform this operation that can accept either type.

Comment: It's still unclear @jack, please provide an example of what you want. Although I don't think what you want is possible or makes sense, but an example would help clarify and I might be wrong.

Comment: I just want to know if it is allowed to typecast a structure type to a basic integer type, and to typecast a basic integer type to a structure type.

Comment: And please add the clarifications to the question body.

Comment: Casting allows pretty much anything, whether it's correct that's a different thing.

Comment: What about a structure that is bigger than the size of an integer on your system? You would be way better off with converting it to strings and vice versa.

Comment: @Zach P, The converted objects are never used, I am just worried about the cast expressions being allowed. I know that the converted objects are on unselected _Generic branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer:

In C you cannot convert an integer (or any scalar value) to a structure type and you cannot convert a structure object to an integer.

You can use pointers (as mentioned by [Qix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510036/qix) in the comments) to achieve the same and then dereference the converted object but it invokes undefined behavior by violating aliasing rules and possibly breaking alignment.

Comment: @Qix, can you please expound on that solution? These are core operations in a performance critical place, is there a way to do this using pointers that would not involve extra instructions?

Comment: Google *pointer aliasing*. It's not hard. Neither is benchmarking. Pre-optimization is going to kill you.