# Is casting a struct to an integer legal?

Tags: c++, struct, language-lawyer, standard-layout

```
struct test{
  int num;
};

int main(){
 struct test t = {1234};
 int n = *((int*)&t); // n = 1234
 
 return 0;
}
```

Is the above snippet legal and causes no undefined behavior? I have seen [this similar code snippet](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/49ca43f9cc4423dfbbf615fb92856d2d1b5a3ab6/src/snapshot/read-only-serializer-deserializer.h#L109) in production.

Edit: Please forgive the C style cast being used here.

Comment: No, that's generally UB.

Comment: any links to explain why?

Comment: a struct can have a conversion to an integer, but your `test` doesnt have one

Comment: you should change your pov. C-style casts are generally wrong, unless you can explain why not.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai does my link include such conversion?

Comment: all relevant code should be in the question

Comment: I dont understand " Please forgive the C style cast being used here." ... the question is about c-style casting, no?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The question is about the use of reinterpret cast

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai all in all if casting struct to an int is UB then it shouldn't matter if it's done inside or outside the struct.

Comment: According to [struct cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) address of the struct is the same as the address of its first member in C. Yet I personally would disapprove such pattern (for what my taste is worth). Such a guarantee seemed to have been removed from C++ [class cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class). To be confirmed in the standard.

Comment: @Dan "inside or outside" ? I dont understand what you mean. You can write a conversion operator `operator int() { return num; }` then you can safely cast a `test` to an `int`.

Comment: @Dan the code in your question is very different from the code in the repo you link. Please decide for what you want to ask and include a [mcve] in the quesiton

Comment: in the repo they cast to `uint32_t` but first member is `int`. Thats a whole different story than `test`

Comment: @Dan The purpose of a conversion operator is to define how to convert from the `struct` to `int`. It doesn't need an internal cast. For example, it can return the `num` member.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai No it's not, both snippets cast an struct to an int.

Comment: @RichardCritten Just for my understanding, what would be the purpose of allowing casting the pointer type if dereferencing would not be allowed? (Yet I would never do that...)

Comment: @Oersted: The address being the same depends. It's still true for a standard layout struct, which this is. There's a little bit of room for question about whether this is defined behavior or not. Even inside the committee, there doesn't seem to be universal agreement about whether it is (or even should be) considered a case of aliasing. Most of the push for treating aliasing as UB was from the push (years ago) to add garbage collection support, which is now being removed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks for the context. From cppreference (which, I agree, is not the standard) it would be valid in C but totally UB in C++.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I tend to err on the side of caution, having an address to something is not the same as having a pointer to and object of which the lifetime has started. Then there is the question of semantics, the struct introduces a semantically new type (so you can for example overload on struct or type) or show intent in code that a function really means to accept the struct (instead of a semantically almost meaningless int).
So for unrelated types, just don't cast. (Some exceptions apply when interacting with hardware).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Generally "address is the same" is not enough to permit the UB-free conversion, but here we have http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4.3, which explicitly allows this.

Comment: @Dan yes it is different. In your code there is an `int` at the address you use for the cast. In the repo there is no `uint32_t` stored at the address they use to cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure

```
struct test{
  int num;
};
```

is a standard layout structure. It is guaranteed that its data member `num` is at zero offset in the structure `test`.

Standard layout structures are useful for communicating with code written in other programming languages as for example in C.

In C the address of an object of a structure type is equal to the address of its first data member.

From the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 15 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units
> in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order
> in which they are declared. **A pointer to a structure object,
> suitably converted, points to its initial member** (or if that member
> is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
> There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
> beginning.

So this code snippet

```
int n = *((int*)&t);
```

is valid and well-formed.

Instead of the C casting it is better to use the C++ casting `reinterpret_cast`.

As **@HolyBlackCat** pointed to in his comment (For example the C++ 20 Standard, 6.8.3 Compound types)

> 4 Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if:
>
> //...
>
> (4.3) — one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the
> first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no
> non-static data members, any base class subobject of that object
> (11.4), or
>
> //...
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same
> address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer
> to the other via a reinterpret_cast

Comment: Also related: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4.3

Comment: Why are you quoting the C standard? A C-style cast in a C++ file is still a C++ cast, and it follows the rules of the C++ standard, not of C. The C standard is only relevant to this question for showing how the C++ behavior creates compatibility with the C behavior.

Comment: @HTNW The quote is provided to show how  a pointer to a structure object and a pointer to its initial member are related  in C.

Comment: But this post essentially says it's UB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30223287 , so who is right?

Comment: @Dan It is a different question unrelated to the given question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it's the exact same topic: 
> You can use pointers to achieve the same and then dereference the converted object but it invokes undefined behavior by violating aliasing rules and possibly breaking alignment.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow let me know what you think of that answer, i have seen a few other spots where it's declared UB.

Comment: @Dan You are mistaken. It is not the same. In your question there is castong a pointer to a structure object to its first data member. And this is important. In the referenced question there is casting a structure object to an integer or a pointer to a structure object to a pointer to an integer.

Comment: So you are just saying if I change my question to `struct test{ char num;};` then do `int n = *((int*)&t);` then it becomes UB? you are just saying as long as the data types match it should be fine?

Comment: @Dan There is all written in teh answer. You may cast a pointer yto a structure object to a pointer to its first data member.

Comment: And to confirm, this can't be done to it's second data member and beyond as there could be padding correct?

Comment: @Dan A pointer to a structure object points to the initial address of the memory occupied  by the object and where its first data member is placed  provided that the structure is a standard layout structure.

Comment: right but what if increment the pointer by the size of it's first member, would it point to its second member or it's UB?

Comment: @Dan How are you going to increment a pointer to a structure object? :) Data members can have different sizes and different alignes. For example the first data member can have the type char and the next can have the type long long. What pointer are you going to increment?

Comment: `struct test{ int a; int b; };  struct test t = {1,2}; int n = *(((int*)&t + 1));` is `n` now showing value of `int b` ? I'm pretty sure this is now UB.

Comment: @Dan This has nothing common with teh meaning of the original question.

Comment: @Dan It is a different question. I need to look through the Standard. Pay attention to that objects can be differently aligned using alingas attribute. As far as I remember in the C Standard there is a reference that the example you provided for a structure with two integers is correct.

Comment: but according to `There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.` it should generally be a bad idea to do this for any other members past the first one, there could be padding.

Comment: @Dan As I said if I am not mistaken there is a reference in the C Standard that you may use the pointer arithmetic with data members shown in the example of a structure with two integers you provided. But I need a time to find the reference.

Comment: Not a problem, thank you.